# Capitalize first word in sentence depending on locale

Tags: java, android

Do you know a way to capitalize the first letter in a sentence depending on locale ?
In english, the first letter is upper case, but there are languages where first letter in sentence it is lower case(or there are no upper/lower cases).

I want to use it into some TextViews, used as titles or descriptions.

Comment: You are getting the other languages from a localized resource I assume?  Why not just capitalize it correctly there already?

Comment: @john16384 my app is using some translations made by volunteers, and the sentences/words list is wrote in such manner that they don't know some of sentences should be capitalized. Therefore, we need to capitalize them ourself.
P.S.: those translations are also not 100% trust worthy

Comment: The problem is that `Locale` has no information about whether sentences should be capitalized or not.  You'd have to make your own list of Locales that donot require capitalization and then lowercase the first char.

Comment: @john16384 thanks, i think i'll do that, since i can't see any other option